# Segments separated by user in Mautic?

Tags: mautic

is it possible to separate segments by user? I tried to do this in Roles->Permissions, but there are only "View others", "Edit others", "Delete others" and "Full access".

Answer (score 0):

By Default I believe the currently logged in user can create, edit, and delete their OWN Segments.

However you can only hide other segments from them if they have no permissions / no checkboxes for this section:

[image: Segment Permissions]

The Mautic permissions system is not built so that you can GRANT access to specific Segments, other than through ownership. So if a group of users needs to access a Segment, you'll have to grant them access to ALL segments.

References:

- https://github.com/mautic/mautic/issues/3716